# SLURM and consecutive jobs

Tags: submit, jobs, slurm

I tried to set up consecutive jobs using SLURM but failed.
At the end of the current job, I successfully  create the folder and input files for the next job. I can also go to that folder, but when I submit it immediately stop. The job gets submitted but then nothing happen, it just stop without any error message.
Here is how I proceed:

```
 cp CONFIG.OUT ../$NEXT_DIR/CONFIG.INI
 cd ../$NEXT_DIR
 pwd
 sbatch run.npt
```

Does anyone know how to submit a SLURM job from a  SLURM script?
I've no problem doing this with LSF.
Thank you,

Eric.

Comment: Does `run.npt` contain the correct `#SBATCH` predirectives?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  Pankrates,

yes it does.
I figured out, I just of to use the array feature of slurm.
Thank you.